# Min/max row-sum distribution of a symmetric matrix of uniform random variables over $[0,1]$ and fixed $1$s along diagonal and scattered $1$s

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, matrices, random-matrices

Given a $n\times n$ symmetric random matrix such that

> 1. all **diagonal** elements are all **fixed** as $0$.
> 2. **randomly select** $k$ distinct cells in the upper triangle (excluding the diagonal), and then **fix** them as $1$. The elements in the lower triangle are set accordingly. Of course $k\le \frac{n^2-n}{2}$.
> 3. all other elements are **independent uniform** random variables over $[0,1]$.

The question is

> Any known result for the distribution of the minimum/maximum row sum?

It is easier to just look at one row. Let $c$ be the number of chosen cells to be fixed as $1$, then its distribution is $\frac{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {n - 1} \\ 
  c 
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{{n^2} - n}}{2} - (n - 1)} \\ 
  {k - c} 
\end{array}} \right)}}{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{{n^2} - n}}{2}} \\ 
  k 
\end{array}} \right)}}$, which equals the probability of $c$ chosen cells in the first row. The sum of the remaining $n-1-c$ cells are i.i.d. uniform, and their sum is Irwin–Hall distribution.

However, I have trouble to find the distribution for min/max row sum, as the row sums are not even independent.

---

A related question is [Bound for largest eigenvalue of symmetric matrices of uniform random variables over $[0,1]$ and fixed $1$s along diagonal and scattered $1$s](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290582/bound-for-largest-eigenvalue-of-symmetric-matrices-of-uniform-random-variables-o).