# Eigenvalue distribution of a special symmetric matrix of uniform random variables

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, random-matrices

Given a $n\times n$ **symmetric** random matrix such that

> 1. all **diagonal** elements are all **fixed** as $0$.
> 2. all other elements in the upper triangle are **uniform random variables** over $[0,1]$. all values in the lower triangle are set accordingly to ensure symmetry.

The question is,

> Is there known exact/or asymptotic ($n \to \infty$) formula for distribution of the largest eigenvalue of such matrix?
>
> *Now as suggested by the comment, the exact formula seems not exist, but still hope someone could help with the asymptotic case.

I am not familiar with random matrix theory, but I think this kind of matrix is not uncommon, and there hopefully should have been some result. Thanks!

Comment: an exact result for any $n$ is unlikely, but for large $n$ you should recover the GOE distribution (Gaussian distribution or uniform distribution should not make difference for large $n$).

Comment: Actually, the mean is $1/2$ and the variance is $1/12$, so you are in the regime that the rank 1 perturbation dominates and the fluctuations are Gaussian. Read the answer (and references) to your previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290582/bound-for-largest-eigenvalue-of-symmetric-matrices-of-uniform-random-variables-o